# Does disabling lock escalation put more stress on the data mdf?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, block, escalation

We have a large multi-use application suffering from OBJECT and PAGE blocks on a number of tables. We are unable to reconsider the design, but need to reduce blocks that affect performance on client machines.
I have been considering disabling lock escalations on one table but need to know what pressure it will put on other resources. The disk i/o is already strained. Will additional, individual locks require more i/o than the automatic table locks? Will it affect our system databases more than our application db?
We don't do full table updates/reads. Each request will only deal with a very small portion of the table.

Comment: There is no chance anybody can provide a meaningful answer here. You haven't provided any details.

Comment: I want to know how having lots more individual locking requests (Row instead of a small number of page/table) will affect the system. Where will the lock information be kept and does having perhaps a thousand row locks cause issues on resources?

Comment: Again...this is so extremely vague the only valid answer is "it depends".

Comment: Presumably you refer to the trace flags 1211  and 1224. Did you read the documentation? Quote: _Using this trace flag can generate excessive numbers of locks. This can slow the performance of the Database Engine, or cause 1204 errors_.  Did you read the "Reduce blocking" [info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323630/how-to-resolve-blocking-problems-that-are-caused-by-lock-escalation-in).

Comment: No. I intent to add lock hints or ALTER TABLE to disable lock escalation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a large multi-use application suffering from OBJECT and **PAGE**
>   blocks on a number of tables.
>
> ...
>
> The disk **i/o** is already strained.
>   Will additional, individual locks require more **i/o** than the automatic
>   table locks?

You misunderstand lock escalation, this is clear from the parts of your question that I made bold.

Lock escalation goes `from rows to table` or `from pages to table` (I excluded partition as it's not your case), so if now you have **page locks** it's **NOT lock escalation**.

Lock granularity is choosen by server unless you use hints (`rowlock`, `paglock`) and if it choses `page locks` there is no escalation. If it then removes all the `page locks` and substitutes them with `table lock`, it means `lock escalation` occured.

The second thing that is wrong is your thinking that locks have to do with `IO`. This is not true. Locks are held in memory and have nothing to do with reads. You can check this article to see how `CPU usage` and `query duration` increase when the locks are more granular: [Why ROWLOCK Hints Can Make Queries Slower and Blocking Worse in SQL Server](https://littlekendra.com/2016/02/04/why-rowlock-hints-can-make-queries-slower-and-blocking-worse-in-sql-server/).

You should understand what causes your lock escalation.

> **Lock Escalation Thresholds**
>
> Lock escalation is triggered when lock escalation is not disabled on
>   the table by using the `ALTER TABLE SET LOCK_ESCALATION` option, and
>   when either of the following conditions exists:
>
> - A single Transact-SQL statement acquires at least 5,000 locks on a    single nonpartitioned table or index.
> - A single Transact-SQL statement acquires at least 5,000 locks on a    single partition of a partitioned table and the 
>     `ALTER TABLE SET LOCK_ESCALATION` option is set to AUTO.
> - The number of locks in an instance of the Database Engine exceeds    memory or configuration thresholds.

[Lock Escalation (Database Engine)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)

So if you reach 5,000 locks per statement threshold you should split your operations to smaller batches.

And if you are under memory pressure, disabling lock escalation will make your situation even worse.

**UPDATE**

I've found this description of locks in the book [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals (Developer Reference)by Kalen Delaney  (Author),‎ Bob Beauchemin (Author),‎ Conor Cunningham (Author),‎ Jonathan Kehayias  (Author),‎ Paul S. Randal (Author),‎ Benjamin Nevarez  (Author](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658560)

> Locks aren’t on-disk structures. You won’t find a lock field directly
>   on a data page or a table header, and the metadata that keeps track of
>   locks is never written to disk. Locks are internal memory structures:
>   They consume part of the memory used for SQL Server. A lock is
>   identified by lock resource, which is a description of the resource
>   that’s locked (a row, index key, page, or table). To keep track of the
>   database, the type of lock, and the information describing the locked
>   resource, each lock requires 64 bytes of memory on a 32-bit system and
>   128 bytes of memory on a 64-bit system. This 64-byte or 128-byte
>   structure is called a lock block.
>   ... The lock manager maintains a lock hash table. Lock resources,
>   contained within a lock block, are hashed to determine a target hash
>   slot in the hash table. All lock blocks that hash to the same slot are
>   chained together from one entry in the hash table. Each lock block
>   contains a 15-byte field that describes the locked resource. The lock
>   block also contains pointers to lists of lock owner blocks. Each of
>   the three states has a separate list for lock owners.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear in my description and understanding. I am considering stopping lock escalation on tables using hints or ALTER table. You say that locks are stored in memory, but if I have excessive locks, are they not written to disk? Will they not be written to the system tables at any point?

Comment: I understood you perfectly, you want to stop lock escalation on some tables. I repeat my answer: first you should consider the CAUSE of your lock escalation, it can be caused by memory pressure, in this case when you stop lock escalation even MORE locks will consume your memory and your situation will be even worse. Second, I repeat it, locks have nothing to do with IO and disks, they are stored in RAM and they are memory and CPU consuming

Comment: I know that the cause of the lock escalation is due to it being a heavily used system with very high reads, not memory constraint, and that escalation is always to table. I am considering using lock_escalation DISABLE and rowhints to stop all non-row locks.
My OQ was if there is any disk use/wait when forcing > 5000 locks on a table. When I read syslockinfo, you are saying this is ONLY mapped to memory and it reads from memory. The table has no physical existence on disk at any time. You have answered this question saying it is never written to disk. Thank you.

Comment: @cloudsafe I updated my answer with lock structure description